# How to add class on term link?

Tags: tags, terms

I am looking for a way to add tag slug as a class.
I can't figure out how to achieve this...

Here is how I display the products tags 
`<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->id, 'product_tag'); ?>`

The output is
`<a href="http://myurl.com" rel="tag">My tag</a>`

And I want
`<a href="http://myurl.com" class="Tag_Slug" rel="tag">My tag</a>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should use a custom loop:

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' );
if ($terms && ! is_wp_error($terms)): ?>
    <?php foreach($terms as $term): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term->slug, 'product_tag'); ?>" rel="tag" class="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yes custom loop was the way ! Thanks.
however it doesn't work. I think there is something wrong with the link ;)

Comment: Sorry, try it now:)

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you wrap the output in an unordered list something like below?

```
echo '<ul class="styles">';
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'styles', '<li>', ',</li><li>', '</li>' );
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: In fact i want to add a unique class on each link ;)

Comment: I don't know why you want unique classes but I would suggest using id's(they are supposed to be unique) instead of class.

Comment: My bad... I haven't read your answer carefully !